# Codeigniter roles for more than one admin

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hello everybody i need help on codeigniter roles or permision. i have one user role (the admin) :

Table users ine the database :

```
id   int(11)    
email    varchar(100)   
password varchar(128)       
name     varchar(100)
```

in my admin panel i have (page.php controller)=page management, page order, (agent.php controller) = add,edit,delete... , (gyms) = add,edit,delete... ,(article.php controller)

and i have 21 sections, for each section i have more than one treatment, what i want is to assign to each section an admin than can edit and view only his section. so i will have 21 section_admin and one (or more) global_admin than can manage everything

i add an other field in users table named type :
type varchar(50)
it will have two values section_admin or global_admin. I searched but i found no tutorial that shows me how do that.

i don't know how to integrate roles management in my system. Can someone help me?

The controler : user.php

```
    class User extends Admin_Controller
            {

                public function __construct ()
                {
                    parent::__construct();
                }

                public function index ()
                {
                    // Fetch all users
                    $this->data['users'] = $this->user_m->get();

                    // Load view
                    $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/user/index';
                    $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->data);
                }

                public function edit ($id = NULL)
                {
                    // Fetch a user or set a new one
                    if ($id) {
                        $this->data['user'] = $this->user_m->get($id);
                        count($this->data['user']) || $this->data['errors'][] = 'User could not be found';
                    }
                    else {
                        $this->data['user'] = $this->user_m->get_new();
                    }

                    // Set up the form
                    $rules = $this->user_m->rules_admin;
                    $id || $rules['password']['rules'] .= '|required';
                    $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);

                    // Process the form
                    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
                        $data = $this->user_m->array_from_post(array('name', 'email', 'password'));
                        $data['password'] = $this->user_m->hash($data['password']);
                        $this->user_m->save($data, $id);
                        redirect('admin/user');
                    }

                    // Load the view
                    $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/user/edit';
                    $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->data);
                }

                public function delete ($id)
                {
                    $this->user_m->delete($id);
                    redirect('admin/user');
                }

                public function login ()
                {
                    // Redirect a user if he's already logged in
                    $dashboard = 'admin/dashboard';
                    $this->user_m->loggedin() == FALSE || redirect($dashboard);

                    // Set form
                    $rules = $this->user_m->rules;
                    $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);

                    // Process form
                    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
                        // We can login and redirect
                        if ($this->user_m->login() == TRUE) {
                            redirect($dashboard);
                        }
                        else {
                            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'That email/password combination does not exist');
                            redirect('admin/user/login', 'refresh');
                        }
                    }

                    // Load view
                    $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/user/login';
                    $this->load->view('admin/_layout_modal', $this->data);
                }

                public function logout ()
                {
                    $this->user_m->logout();
                    redirect('admin/user/login');
                }

                public function _unique_email ($str)
                {
                    // Do NOT validate if email already exists
                    // UNLESS it's the email for the current user

                    $id = $this->uri->segment(4);
                    $this->db->where('email', $this->input->post('email'));
                    !$id || $this->db->where('id !=', $id);
                    $user = $this->user_m->get();

                    if (count($user)) {
                        $this->form_validation->set_message('_unique_email', '%s should be unique');
                        return FALSE;
                    }

                    return TRUE;
                }
            }
```

The model user_m.php :

```
                protected $_table_name = 'users';
                protected $_order_by = 'name';
                public $rules = array(
                    'email' => array(
                        'field' => 'email', 
                        'label' => 'Email', 
                        'rules' => 'trim|required|valid_email|xss_clean'
                    ), 
                    'password' => array(
                        'field' => 'password', 
                        'label' => 'Password', 
                        'rules' => 'trim|required'
                    )
                );
                public $rules_admin = array(
                    'name' => array(
                        'field' => 'name', 
                        'label' => 'Name', 
                        'rules' => 'trim|required|xss_clean'
                    ), 
                    'email' => array(
                        'field' => 'email', 
                        'label' => 'Email', 
                        'rules' => 'trim|required|valid_email|callback__unique_email|xss_clean'
                    ), 
                    'password' => array(
                        'field' => 'password', 
                        'label' => 'Password', 
                        'rules' => 'trim|matches[password_confirm]'
                    ),
                    'password_confirm' => array(
                        'field' => 'password_confirm', 
                        'label' => 'Confirm password', 
                        'rules' => 'trim|matches[password]'
                    ),
                );

                function __construct ()
                {
                    parent::__construct();
                }

                public function login ()
                {
                    $user = $this->get_by(array(
                        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                        'password' => $this->hash($this->input->post('password')),
                    ), TRUE);

                    if (count($user)) {
                        // Log in user
                        $data = array(
                            'name' => $user->name,
                            'email' => $user->email,
                            'id' => $user->id,
                            'loggedin' => TRUE,
                        );
                        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
                    }
                }

                public function logout ()
                {
                    $this->session->sess_destroy();
                }

                public function loggedin ()
                {
                    return (bool) $this->session->userdata('loggedin');
                }

                public function get_new(){
                    $user = new stdClass();
                    $user->name = '';
                    $user->email = '';
                    $user->password = '';
                    return $user;
                }

                public function hash ($string)
                {
                    return hash('sha512', $string . config_item('encryption_key'));
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

There's too many ways how you can incorporate permission system in your project and it all depends what you need. I will give you a basic idea for your case how I would do it IF I understood your question right:

1. Yes, you can add another field to user table and call it role
2. To your section table add a user_id field. This is how you connect user with section.
3. Once user logs in, veryfy if that user is section_user and if yes you need to pull the right section based on that user_id from db.
4. If not, it means its a global_admin and then display all sections.

I'm not sure if I understood your question right tho.

Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Save yourself the trouble and use this: [Flexi-Auth](http://haseydesign.com/flexi-auth/). You'll have roles and permissions for all the admin types you want for example.

Comment: It is explained in the link, you need to integrate the code in your project.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve, but I'll explain roughly what I would do:

**1) Define a URL scheme**

For example if you had a website for car enthusiasts, each brand might be its own section:

```
somesite.com/section/honda
somesite.com/section/ford
somesite.com/section/toyota
```

Those URL slugs (honda, ford, toyota etc) effectively become the identifiers for the section you're trying to access. Each one is unique.

You would then want to make sure that each slug after /section/ is a parameter rather than a function call. You can do this by going into /application/config/routes.php and defining a route like this:

```
$route['section/(:any)'] = section_controller/$1; 
// $1 is the placeholder variable for the (:any) regex. So anything that comes after /section will be used as a parameter in the index() function of the section_controller class.
```

**2. Create a new database called 'section', and a corresponding model**

For now just give it two fields: *section_id*, and *section_name*. This will store each unique section. The code for the model would be something like this:

```
class Section extends CI_Model
{
    public $section_name;
    public $section_id;

    public function loadByName($section_name)
    {
         $query = $this->db->select('section_id', 'section_name')
                        ->from('section')
                        ->where('section_name', $section_name);

         $row = $query->row();

         $this->section_name = $row->section_name;
         $this->section_id = $row->section_id;

         return $row;
    }

    public function loadById($section_id)
    {
         $query = $this->db->select('section_id', 'section_name')
                           ->from('section')
                           ->where('section_id', $section_id);

         $row = $query->row();

         $this->section_name = $row->section_name;
         $this->section_id = $row->section_id;

         return $row;
    }
}
```

**3. In the user table, create an additional field called *section_id***

This will be the reference to the ID of the section which they are an admin of. For example if the Toyota section_id is 381, then use 381 as the number in the section_id field in the user table.

**4. When the page is requested, look up the section_id based on the slug name.**

In your controller file, you should then load the section model somewhere in the index() method like so:

```
class Section_controller extends CI_Controller
{

    public function index($section_name)
    {
          // I will assume you've already loaded your logged in User somewhere

          $this->load->model('Section');
          $this->Section->loadByName($section_name);

          if ($this->User->section_id == $this->Section->section_id)
          {
              // Render the page with appropriate permissions
          }
          else
          {
              // Throw an error
          }
    }
}
```

I won't get into any more specifics of doing all of that; you'll have to read the Codeigniter documentation for a grasp on how to handle routes, controllers, DB queries etc.

Comment: but i must have for each section his own controler and i must have a user (a global user = global admin) that can manage all sections and also can access to the page controller and register controller for example.

Comment: I have 22section and every section have his own gallery, program, members, rules, activities, archives.

Comment: Addressing your site architecture is I think a little too out of scope for a SO answer. But solving the problem boils down to this:

1. Know what section you're on either by it's unique ID or its name
2. Determine the ID of the section your admin is supposed to manage
3. Compare the two
4. And of course it's very easy to include global admin privileges with a simple condition in an if statement.

Answer (score 0):

> if you have only 2 roles then it can achieve easily. you know the user is admin or not if user >is admin then it activate all the section where admin has acess. if user is then he won,t able >to gain access.
>
> if you are comfortalbe to use tankauth authentication library if you have enough time to do task then go to tankauth.
>
> you can also use bonfire(HMVC) for user authentication.